# Screen controller driver

Tags: drivers, graphics

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS, 64 bit Linux, in two desktop PCs, both with the same motherboard card: MSI MS-7788, with Intel I5 and 8 GB RAM.

The incorporated graphics adapter is a: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller.

I wonder if there is some available upgrading to this controller,

It is because more than one graphical apps ask me some graphic functions not present here.

How could I get some upgrading about this?

Comment: What graphic functions aren't present?

Comment: I don't know! I'm not a programmer, so... But, some software, like SweetHome3D, doesn't show some specific characteristics because.. something is missed in my graphics part of the system..

Comment: What are the exact error messages, so we can start to understand what's missing, if anything?

Comment: There is no error messages. For example: Sweet Home 3d has the characteristic to show the furniture as a real aerial view or as an icon. Here, I just can see the icon and, according to that software help, this happens when there is some problem with the graphic drivers. BUT... The curious thing is, with the old version of that program, in this exactly same machine and Linux system, I could see the full aerial image!!! Another example is with some characteristics of GoogleEarth I cannot to use because the drivers (according to the software help). So...